# Reset System Loop on my Hp elitebook while setting up dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, reset

1
I have set dual-boot system of windows 10 and ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop. After installation it said that it succeeded. But while rebooting it says "reset system" and keeps repeating that message. My bios mode was legacy. And my laptop is of Hp elitebook series. What should I do now? Kindly help.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KcJRXjQcmz/

Comment: Did you try the suggested fix from bootrepair? It's saying that it will install the grub bootloader onto your MBR which is standard for legacy boot, non-efi systems. Currently, it's using an efi type setup and so grub is installed to your `/dev/sda6` partition. If you have booted windows since installation, make sure fastboot is disabled for windows and also make sure windows is not in a hibernated state (windows must be completely shut down and also not in fastboot). When installed to the MBR, the Grub bootloader should detect windows and Ubuntu and allow you to select the OS when you boot up

Comment: FYI, it's always recommended you have an installation media ready for Windows in case you need to reinstall Windows if something goes wrong. Also, a backup of your files. According to boot repair, however, everything looks good and it just needs to install Grub to your MBR so you can use legacy mode.

Comment: I tried to do the suggested fix but it says -  LegacyWindows detected. Please enable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB). Can you please tell me what should I do now?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You probably want to make that paste public and not behind a login if you want more people to see it.